# Django-Admin how to handle erros in save_model():

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a simple model with a `FileField` and I want to deal with files before finally saving them. So What I did, was overwriting the `save_model()` method and everything works. Now I wanted to implement error handling, and I feel I should have used another method to do my validating (maybe `clean()`?):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    if "file" in form.changed_data:
        if ok:
            proceed
        else:
            raise Error
```

I need to differentiate between the file types of the uploaded file, before saving them (zips need to unpacked first, then saved and other things).

Answer (score 0):

You should use form's **clean()** method for validation of form fields.

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        ...
        ... # other validation if need

        if "file" in self.changed_data:
            if not ok:
                raise error
```

It is better way to show error message to the client side.